# Frame of WPF app with possibility to insert own animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am looking for an advice on the following idea.

Is there any solution to create a frame of WPF application providing some functionalities, where someone else could easily insert his own animation to our code?

As an example, we can provide an application with voice recognition functionality that could be easily used to create simple game by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggesting giving a look to MEF: http://mef.codeplex.com/

> The Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) is a composition layer for
>   .NET that improves the flexibility, maintainability and testability of
>   large applications. MEF can be used for third-party plugin
>   extensibility, or it can bring the benefits of a loosely-coupled
>   plugin-like architecture to regular applications.

Most of the context in which I've heard of it being used is in support of a plugin-oriented architecture, which sounds like what you're doing.